# PHP While loop to populate option field

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to  autofill the date function for a dropdown. I thought it would be a fairly straightforward bit of code. I've searched online and fiddled with it for about an hour now and still no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
$day = 1;
while ($day < 32) {
echo "<option value=/"$day/"> $day </option>";
$day++;
}
```

Comment: `echo "<option value=\"$day\"> $day </option>";`

Answer (score 3):

In order to escape quotes and double quotes, your slashes need to be backslashes like below.

```
$day = 1;
while ($day < 32) {
  echo "<option value=\"{$day}\"> $day </option>";
  $day++;
}
```

It's also a good idea to wrap variables that aren't appended to a string using `.` with curly braces `{}`. If you get in the habit, performing tasks like printing an array value will be much easier later on.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to coding still so I had forgotten about needing to use the other slash for escaping. :) This will definitely help me for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a for loop?

The **for** way:

```
for($day=1;$day<32;$day++)   
    echo "<option value=\"{$day}\">$day</option>";
```

Your **while** way:

```
$day=1
while($day < 32){

    echo "<option value=\"{$day}\">$day</option>";
    $day++;
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I like the compactness of the for loop. I had not thought of it as I'm only 1 week into my first PHP class. After the input of their birth date is finished, I'll be working on having it output the amount of days the person has been alive. (The assignment only called for assigning variables and showing them on the next page... I like to overachieve. >.> )

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this on your code. instead of using slashes to scape your double quotes, i dont think they're different but this looks alot cleaner than all those slashes

```
$day = 1;
while ($day < 32) {
echo  "<option value='".$day."'> $day </option>";
$day++;
}
```